# iOS Swift MapKit will not reload

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, reload

I have a MapKit View on my storyboard - set to hidden. With the following code I can unhide it from view using a button(1) click and it loads perfectly. Another button(2) click will hide the map. The issue is reloading the map. How do I reload the map with button(1). Currently, the map will not show again.

Here is the entire code to load the map:

```
@IBAction func ButtonOne(sender: UIButton) {
    self.myMap()

}//End Button(1)

@IBAction func ButtonTwo(sender: UIButton) {
    self.mapView.hidden = true

}//End Button(2)

func myMap() {
    let userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
        userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)

    self.mapView.hidden = false
    self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height * 0.75)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: In myMap, log (println) the values of self.mapView (make sure it's not nil) and screenSize (make sure it's not 0,0).

Comment: Anna: Here are the values of self.mapView: button(1) (<MKMapView: 0x12462e290; frame = (0 0; 375 500.25); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x17423c260>>) and button(1:clicked the second time) (<MKMapView: 0x12462e290; frame = (0 0; 375 500.25); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x17423c260>>)

Comment: mapView looks ok assuming that println is _after_ the frame is updated.  By "map will not show again", do you mean the correct user location is not shown (is the screen all blue meaning ocean) or that the map itself is not shown and you can see the view under the map view?

Comment: Anna: I placed the println() in the myMap func under self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height * 0.75)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true) and The MapView does show at all the second time

Comment: Then it must be something other than in the code shown which looks ok.

Comment: OK. It seems to come back into view when I rotate the device. I also wrapped it in: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...} and still nothing - any other suggestions? What would make it come back into view when I rotate the device?

Comment: Maybe check the autolayout constraints.  The parent view might be going off screen taking the map view with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to use 'exit(1)' when disconnecting/hiding then map when the call ends. BTT the user will really have no use for still being able to use the app.